# How electromagnet reacts to 6v vs. 12v

Tags: towing, cadillac, trailer-brakes

I am wanting to pull my car trailer with a 1950 Cadillac. The car is running with the original 6 volt system. The trailer is a dual axle with brakes on each axle. The system on the trailer is 12 volt. Changing the bulbs is obvious. How will the brakes react to 1/2 the volts (6), but two times the amps (ohms law)? The vehicle has plenty of power and weight, however, not having the added stopping power while pulling a trailer is sketchy at best. Any help is appreciated, Brad

Comment: I would expect little or no braking.  With half voltage you will have half current, not double, as the resistance of the brake magnets is constant.

Comment: Ohm's Law says they will have half the amps if they have half the volts.

Comment: Does the vehicle have a trailer brake controller installed, or are the brake magnets simply connected to the brake light circuits?

Comment: If you can't change the brakes for ones which run off 6V then you're going to need a local 12V battery on the trailer, a boost charger for it, and a controller of some sort (which might be a simple as a relay).